# Is there a function I can use in Python to randomly select elements equal to specified number and change it to another?

Tags: python, numpy, random, jupyter-notebook

For instance, if I have the following distribution, I want to randomly select 4 elements = 1 and change that element to = 0.

```
lst = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

-> Function <-

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

or

```
lst = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or ....

Comment: Get a list of the indexes of all the `1` elements. Use `random.choices()` to select 4 of those indexes, and change them to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```py
ones = np.where(lst)[0]
to_zero = np.random.choice(ones, 4, replace=False)
for i in to_zero: # Alternatively, if lst is an array: lst[to_zero] = 0
  lst[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you first need to get the list of the indexes of the one elements. Then you need to pick 4 random indexes and update the values from the starting list.
Note that you cannot use the `random.choices` method because it doesn’t return unique values, use `random.sample` instead.

```py
def update_randomly(tab):
    n = range(len(tab))
    one_indexes = [i for i in n if tab[i] == 1]
    rdm_indexes = random.sample(one_indexes, 4)
    return [0 if i in rdm_indexes else tab[i] for i in n]
```